# Order of css resources using Fanstatic

Tags: ckan, fanstatic

I'm trying to import multiple css resources in my own CKAN theme using Fanstatic like this:

```
{% resource 'my_fanstatic_library/b.css' %}
{% resource 'my_fanstatic_library/a.css' %}
```

Unfortunately CKAN renders them in alphabetical order:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/fanstatic/mytheme/:version:2015-05-11T14:07:18/a.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/fanstatic/mytheme/:version:2015-05-11T14:07:18/b.css" />
```

To overwrite the order I tried to create a `resource.config`-file with the following content:

```
[main]

order = b.css a.css

[custom render order]

b.css = 1
a.css = 2

[depends]

a.css = b.css
```

But sadly there was no change in the rendering order. I placed the `resource.config` file in the `mytheme/fanstatic/` folder and moved it to `mytheme/` but nothing helped.

Answer (score 0):

`order` and `custom render order` both work for me, however `depends` just throws an error. Your `resource.config` file should be at `mytheme/resource.config`.

I need to restart the server after making changes to `resource.config`, however.

Which version of CKAN are you running and which server do yo use?

Answer (score 0):

When creating resource config file make it inside fantastic folder. Annd syntax should be,

[main]
order = css/b.css css/a.css

[depends]
css/a.css = css/b.css

This is a good example: https://github.com/ckan/ckanext-pages/blob/master/ckanext/pages/theme/public/resource.config